# How do I use a variable as part of a directory name in a MS DOS batch file (Windows 7)?

Tags: dos

For example, if I set variable var equal to 20110804 in a batch file (SET var = 20110804), I would then like to use this variable to navigate to a directory like C:\folder\20110804.

My thought was to write a batch file like this:

```
SET var = 20110804

c:
cd \folder\%var%
```

However, when I run this program, the batch file actually just ignores the `%var%` part and send me to `C:\folder\`.

Any tips?

Comment: There is no MS-DOS in Windows 7 .... there's a Windows 7 command shell - but that's a far cry from "MS-DOS" ....

Answer (score 5):

Make sure there are no spaces around the equals sign.

i.e. Instead of :

SET var = 20110804

Do :

SET var=20110804